# The validity of values received from external sources shall be checked

Tags: c, callback, misra

Polyspace reports following violation

> The validity of values received from external sources shall be checked

```
 Std_ReturnType ProductionState (uint8 * Data)
{
    if (Data != NULL_PTR) {
        *Data = 0x00u;
        return(E_OK);
    }

    return(E_NOT_OK);
}
```

Why is this reported? Which are further checks needed to avoid this MISRA violation?

Comment: You should check external data for buffer overflow.

Comment: There's not enough code nor context to answer the question. Basically MISRA-C enforces that you check the error result returned from functions. It does not enforce that you check parameters against NULL etc. Nor does it care about specific things like buffer overflow during input (MISRA bans the whole of stdio.h too).

Comment: How do you mean to check external data for buffer overflow ?

Comment: Have you looked at what Directive 4.14 (introduced by MISRA C:2012 Amendment 1) has to say?

Comment: I  have looked, however the example that is in it does not give me hint what to do..